# Bash export errors when ssh-ing in

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

Context: I am running an Ubuntu 22.04.1 virtual machine on my firewall using trueNAS and I solely interact with it using ssh

Whenever I start a new terminal session I get these two messages:

```
-bash: export: `PATH#': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `15': not a valid identifier
```

This issue has been happening for awhile and I have not noticed it causing any other issues. I haven't tried anything since I don't know what the problem is.

Edits:

Output for

```
grep -P 'export .*(15|PATH#)' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
```

is

```
/etc/profile:export PATH# OpenJDK 15
```

Comment: What does `grep export ~/.bashrc` return? If this does not return the offending lines that start with `export 15` and/or `export PATH#` check `grep export ~/.profile` and `grep export /etc/profile`, `grep export /etc/environment` and `grep export /etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: @mchid no need for separate commands. Thewolfhearted please [edit] your question and show us the output of running `grep -P 'export .*(15|PATH#)' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null` on your Ubuntu machine.

Comment: @terdon Yeah, I figured that most people sanitize their username and didn't want to have to go through with explaining all of that. Although, I probably should've put `/etc/environment` as the second or third on the list so the first three would be the most likely ones.

Comment: Oh, it was more about not making the OP run one grep per file when they can just run a single grep on all files. I happen to have a little function for this, so I took the list of files from there, I assumed we suggested the same ones.

Comment: @terdon Fixed it! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space missing in front of `#`.

Add the space manually with an editor or run,

```bash
sudo sed -i 's/PATH#/PATH #/' /etc/profile
```

Comment: Doing the command provides a strange list of things that I provided above, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: sorry, I forgot the `-i` flag

Comment: With the  -i  flag it provides no errors but still does not fix the issue.

Comment: My fault ... the command is correcft, but your issue is in `/etc/profile`, not in `~/.profile`. I edited once again, that should do it.

Comment: im gonna remove the stuff regarding this since they are not needed for future use